# Object Oriented Programming in python "" For finding area of triangle where lengths and angles are given""

Tags: python, error-handling

```
class Triangle(self, side_A, side_B, side_C, angle):
    
    self.side_A = side_A
    self.side_B = side_B
    self.side_C = side_C
    self.angle = angle
    
    
    def area(side_A, side_B, side_C):
        return side_A * side_B * side_C
    
    def area_of_given_angle(side_A, side_B, angle):
        return side_A  * side_B * math.sin(angle)
```

WHAT IS MISTAKE IN THIS CODE
Yeah its about finding area of triangle.

length of side to be given and answer to be displayed
same thing when two sides a and b length are given with an angle which can trigonometric ratio

Comment: Classes do not take parameters - you need to look at classes and `__init__`. Methods in a class also take `self` as the first argument, unless they are decorated as a`@staticmethod`.

Comment: Basicly, everything about this code is wrong. Starting from class definition, passing parameters to a function, to the math formulas themselves.

Comment: This documentation about Python objects might be useful: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects